# Why the output of z variable is 19? How does that code works more clearly?

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

I am having the following program in c++;

```c
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i=1, j=1, k=1, z=0;
    for (; i <= 10; i++)
        while(j <= 10) {
            j++;
            do {
                k++;
                z++;
            } while(k <= 10);
        }
    std::cout << z << " ";
}
```

The output is 19 when running and I cannot wrap my head why it is that.

I was expecting the return to be 10 because of the previous while(j<=10). I am missing something?

Comment: You should indent the code properly. If not for yourself, at least for the people you're asking for help.

Comment: The inner loop runs (at least) once for each outer loop, even if k > 10.

Comment: Put a `cout << j << k << z << std::endl;` inside the `do` loop, or better yet, step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: Note that `j` isn't reset for the next `for` loop. In subsequent `for` loops, `while(j <= 10)` is always false. Always define and initialize your variables at the scope where they are needed.

Comment: Not sure what is this code supposed to achieve, but this is probably just an exercise to encourage you to use a debugger and step through the execution.

Comment: Thank everyone for the kind help!! Amazing people and community! It is a exercise and couldn't understand what is behind it at all.

Comment: Same  for `k` which is only initialised once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The do while loop that is a sub-statement of the while loop

```
while(j<=10) {
    j++;
    do {
        k++;
        z++;
  } while(k<=10);
```

is executed 10 times due to the condition of the while loop

```
while(j<=10) {
```

In the first iteration of the loop within the inner do-while loop the variable `z` becomes equal to `10`. On the other hand, the variable `k` will be equal to `11` due to the condition of the do-while loop

```
    do {
        k++;
        z++;
  } while(k<=10);
```

In the next `9` iterations of the outer while loop the inner do while loop will iterate only one time because after the first iteration of the while loop the variable `k` will be greater than `10`.

So after the first iteration of the while loop the variable `z` will be equal to `10` and in the next `9` iteration of the while loop the variable `z` will be increased each time only once.

That is do-while loops always have at least one iteration because their conditions are checked after executing their sub-statements.